# Access DB not displaying in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is driving me nuts.  I've seen other responses to this type of question but it hasn't helped.  I created a simple Access db and want to display the tables in a datagrid.  I've created something similar which worked yet when I try it with this, it won't display.  How can I check if the connection is actually working?  Code being used is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace CAStock
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Products";

                updateDataGrid(sqlStr);
            }

            private void updateDataGrid(String pSqlStr)
            {
                string connStr = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source = Stock.accdb";
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(pSqlStr,connStr);
                dTable.Clear();
                dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
                dAdapter.Dispose();
                dgvStock.DataSource = dTable;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any exception ?

Comment: Try to move the call to updateDataGrid in the Form1 constructor and see if you get any error message there.

Comment: Verify your database location.  It usually isn't in the same path as the executable, especially when using Visual Studio.

Comment: I get no exception - this same code works with another database and I've literally just copied the code, but for some reason it won't display on this.  The location of the database is stored in the Debug/Bin location

Comment: Sounds like your table is empty.

Comment: Nope - not empty at all.